# Debug Mapbox Android NDK library

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, mapbox

I am attempting to follow the Android Studio Experimental Plugin User Guide instructions located at:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

to modify the Mapbox GL Native library located at:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native

In specific, I have modified the following Android files:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/build.gradle

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/build.gradle

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/build.gradle

My goal is to modify the library so I can debug it. Ideally I would be able to use Android Studio to build the library and debug the C/C++ code. So far I can build it, but I can't debug it. A programmer working at Mapbox told me they don't how to debug the Android code either, so I suspect this isn't an easy goal to reach.

I have made many different attempts to apply the Android Studio Experimental Plugin User Guide instructions, but I'm not experienced at Gradle and my latest attempt is leaving me with the following error message which I don't understand:

> Gradle 'android' project refresh failed 
>   Error:Cause:org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject

Does anyone know how to modify these files to have them build a debuggable Android NDK Library? What is causing the above error?

I am using:

```
> Linux Mint 17.2 
> Android Studio 2.1.1 
> Build #AI-143.2821654, built on April 28, 2016 
> JRE: 1.8.0_65-b17 amd64 
> JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Below are the 4 files as I currently have them modified. Since I am new to Gradle, do not assume I have made any modfications correctly. I was merely attempting to apply the Android Studio Experimental Plugin User Guide instructions until I got a successful build.

Thanks

---

```
#// mapbox-gl-native/platform/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

#Thu Apr 07 14:21:05 CDT 2016

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#//distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip
#//distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip
distributionSha256Sum=e77064981906cd0476ff1e0de3e6fef747bd18e140960f1915cca8ff6c33ab5c
```

---

```
// mapbox-gl-native/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.0-alpha2'
        classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:220bf7a88a7072df3ed16dc8466fb144f2817070'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
```

---

```
// mapbox-gl-native/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

allprojects {
    group project.GROUP
    version project.VERSION_NAME

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.mapzen.android:lost:1.1.0'
}

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_MIN_SDK)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-public'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkAllWarnings true
        warningsAsErrors true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
            buildConfigField "String", "MAPBOX_EVENTS_USER_AGENT_BASE", new StringBuilder().append("\"").append("MapboxEventsAndroid/").append(project.VERSION_NAME).append("\"").toString()
        }

        release {
            jniDebuggable false
            buildConfigField "String", "MAPBOX_EVENTS_USER_AGENT_BASE", new StringBuilder().append("\"").append("MapboxEventsAndroid/").append(project.VERSION_NAME).append("\"").toString()
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
}

model {
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.name
    task "javadoc$name"(type: Javadoc) {
        description = "Generates javadoc for build $name"
        failOnError = false
        destinationDir = new File(destinationDir, variant.baseName)
        source = files(variant.javaCompile.source)
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(android.bootClasspath)
        exclude '**/R.java', '**/BuildConfig.java', 'com/almeros/**'
        options.windowTitle("Mapbox Android SDK $VERSION_NAME Reference")
        options.docTitle("Mapbox Android SDK $VERSION_NAME")
        options.header("Mapbox Android SDK $VERSION_NAME Reference")
        options.bottom("&copy; 2015&ndash;2016 Mapbox. All rights reserved.")
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/")
        options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference/", "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/docs/reference")
        options.overview("src/main/java/overview.html")
        options.group("Mapbox Android SDK", "com.mapbox.*")
        options.group("Third Party Libraries", "com.almeros.*")
        // TODO exclude generated R, BuildConfig, com.almeros.*
    }
}
}

checkstyle {
    configFile project.file('../checks.xml')
    showViolations true
}

/*
task cleanJNIBuilds {
    def jniLibsDir = new File("MapboxGLAndroidSDK/src/main/jniLibs")
    delete jniLibsDir.absolutePath
}
*/

model
{
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    def checkstyle = project.tasks.create "checkstyle${name.capitalize()}", Checkstyle
    checkstyle.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    checkstyle.source variant.javaCompile.source
    checkstyle.classpath = project.fileTree(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir)
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BuildConfig.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/R.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/com/almeros/android/multitouch/**')
    project.tasks.getByName("check").dependsOn checkstyle
}

// From https://raw.github.com/mcxiaoke/gradle-mvn-push/master/jar.gradle
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def jarTask = project.tasks.create(name: "jar${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar) {
        from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
        exclude "**/R.class"
        exclude "**/BuildConfig.class"
    }
    jarTask.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    artifacts.add('archives', jarTask);
}
}

// From https://raw.github.com/mcxiaoke/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle
def isReleaseBuild() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

def getReleaseRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL :
            "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

def getSnapshotRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL :
            "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('USERNAME') ? USERNAME :
            (hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : "")
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('PASSWORD') ? PASSWORD :
            (hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : "")
}


task apklib(type: Zip) {
    appendix = extension = 'apklib'

    from 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    into('res') {
        from 'res'
    }
    into('src') {
        from 'src'
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives apklib
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(),
                            password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(),
                            password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }

/*
                // Leaving out as artifact was incorrectly named when found
                addFilter('aar') { artifact, file ->
                    artifact.name == archivesBaseName
                }
                addFilter('apklib') { artifact, file ->
                    artifact.name == archivesBaseName + '-apklib'
                }
*/

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    model {
    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
        classpath = files(android.bootClasspath)
    }
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    model {
    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}


task makeClean(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '../../'
    commandLine 'make', 'clean'
}

task makeAndroid(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '../../'
    commandLine 'make', 'android'
}

task makeAndroidAll(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '../../'
    commandLine 'make', 'apackage'
}
```

---

```
// mapbox-gl-native/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task accessToken {
    def tokenFile = new File("MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/res/values/developer-config.xml")
    if (!tokenFile.exists()) {
        String tokenFileContents = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                "<resources>\n" +
                "    <string name=\"mapbox_access_token\">" + "$System.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN" + "</string>\n" +
                "</resources>"

        if (tokenFileContents == null) {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("You must set the MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable.")
        }
        tokenFile.write(tokenFileContents)
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    // preBuild.dependsOn('accessToken')
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'
}

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.testapp"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "4.1.0"

        // Specify AndroidJUnitRunner as the default test instrumentation runner
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkAllWarnings true
        warningsAsErrors true
        disable 'IconDensities'
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // run code coverage reports
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':MapboxGLAndroidSDK')) {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    // Leak Canary
    //debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
    //releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'

    // Directions SDK
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-directions:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Geocoder SDK
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-geocoder:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
}

checkstyle {
    configFile project.file('../checks.xml')
    showViolations true
}

model {
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    def checkstyle = project.tasks.create "checkstyle${name.capitalize()}", Checkstyle
    checkstyle.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    checkstyle.source variant.javaCompile.source
    checkstyle.classpath = project.fileTree(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir)
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BuildConfig.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/R.java')
    project.tasks.getByName("check").dependsOn checkstyle
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into the original, more "manual" ways of building ndk libraries via ndk-build, etc.  Also, typically the .so installed on the device via the apk is going to be stripped of debug information - while you point the debugger itself (running on the development host) at the larger, unstripped version.  Also consider if an interactive debug sessions is truly worth the effort, vs. deducing the likely problematic areas of the code and instrumenting them with log output.

Comment: Can you explain more re: "typically the .so installed on the device via the apk is going to be stripped of debug information - while you point the debugger itself (running on the development host) at the larger, unstripped version. "? Are you saying there is some technique to allow the debugger access to the unstripped/debug version of the library?  I have considered if interactive debugging is worth it, but since I have to modify the library in serious ways, I thought it would be worth it. Now I'm not so sure given the difficulty of doing so.

Comment: Remote debugging is almost always done by running a stripped executable (or in this case library) on the target and invoking the debugger on the development host with the location of a more complete file.  If you use the ndk-build method and either explicitly or implicitly end up with -g in the compilation flags you will should multiple .so's in the output tree, the larger ones probably unstripped, which are what you want to feed to ndk-gdb on the host.  But it's rare that insightful use of debug output can't solve a problem - cleverness usually trumps tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradle approach is essentially rewriting or porting the Android SDK Makefile to gradle.  To solve what you are doing on Linux, you will likely need to modify the existing Makefiles.

The reason is that the [Mapbox Android SDK build process](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/CONTRIBUTING_OSX.md) uses `make android` to build the target `libmapbox-gl.so`.  The Gradle project you have includes the `.so` file in with your usual Java code.

`make android` makes a call into [mapbox-gl-native/Makefile](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/Makefile#L150)

and also generates `mapbox-gl-native/build/android-arm-v7/Makefile`, which you may have to research how to modify to generate debug information as Chris Stratton mentions in the comments above.

When you do get around to modifying your C++, you will then need to modify the `settings.gradle` to make use of your modified .so for Android.

```
include ':MapboxGLAndroidSDK'
project(':MapboxGLAndroidSDK').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '<relative-path-to>/../mapbox-gl-native/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK')
include ':app'
```

Another thing to consider — Can you build a debuggable version for Linux?

We have successfully debugged C++ for the Mapbox SDK using the Xcode debugger, as we built an iOS app as well.  I know this will not fit your exact needs, but I mention it in case anyone else in your lab or organization has access to Xcode on OS X and can start debugging using `make iproj`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am working by myself so I don't have access to Xcode. :-(  Still, seems like a good suggestion to simply change over to building a debuggable version for Linux, assuming that will be easier to debug. I already have a debug version of libmapbox-gl.so, no worries there. I'm not sure how to "point" to the debug source on my local after loading the app. I'll have to do some research there. Still would be nice to debug on Android since in the end the app will be mobile.

Comment: Migrating from .gypi build files to Gradle will be worth your while so you can debug in Android Studio, and you may want to open source the Gradle build files after you are done as others may find it useful.  The work you'll need to do is convert this file to from .gypi to Gradle using the link you posted above and this build source.  Good luck!! https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/platform.gyp

Comment: If I can get this to work, I will definitely share what I have. I see the linked file you posted, but I don't know what at .gypi file is used for. Is this a Gradle thing or and Android thing? How can I learn about this file? I obtained the Gradle files I have listed above from Mapbox, so I'm unclear what you mean by "Migrating from .gypi build files to Gradle"? I thought the Mapbox files were Gradle files.

Comment: I have ran across GYP when working with the Chromium source base (incorrectly called .gypi above).  For Mapbox, I imagine they use GYP as it allows them to build for Android, LInux, OS X, iOS, and QT.  This may explain why they don't have an Androd Studio specific build https://gyp.gsrc.io

Comment: Everything in this file [https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/platform.gyp], would need to be ported to Gradle.

Comment: You can also go to Roblabs.com and send me a PM, if you want to collaborate further, then we can work out a solution and post the findings back here.

Comment: I visited your website, but I'm not sure how to contact you. I assume that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GYP_(software) is the gyp you mean. I'm still unclear if this means the Gradle files are generated from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/platform.gyp or if the Gradle files were handwritten to replace an older build system. Mapbox does have an Android Build, I have built it and used it. I have not been able to debug the Android source code using it. I think I am missing something. I'm happy to work with you to figure this out if you are up for that.